# How to get average intervals of records in BigQuery in seconds

Tags: google-bigquery, average, intervals

I'm trying to get the average intervals of records in BigQuery using standardSql. I've looked at some examples but can't get it to work.

```
select timestamp_diff(timestamp, MIN(timestamp), MAX(timestamp)) / (COUNT(DISTINCT(timestamp), SECOND) 
from `data-analysis.customer_analytics._aoi_table`
where flight_number = 'JL540' AND icao_address = '851958'
order by timestamp
```

Below is my table as an image, I want to get the average interval between records in column timestamp.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This worked:

```sql
select 
timestamp_diff(max(timestamp),
min(timestamp),SECOND) / (COUNT(DISTINCT(timestamp)) - 1) 
from `ais-data-analysis.customer_analytics.itochu_aoi_table`
where flight_number = 'JL540' 
AND icao_address = '851958'
```